Django: Objects that live throughout server lifetime
I have some data in csv format that I need to load into the application once and then reuse it throughout the lifetime of the application, which is across multiple requests. How can I do that?
An obvious method for me is to have a module that will load the data and then expose it. However, I don't like modules doing a lot of work, because then imports lead to unexpected side effects. I would like to do that one-time work in a predictable, deterministic fashion, not because someone imported a module.
Does Django provide some hooks for globals? Some kind of Application/Service class where I could do that work and then access the data in the requests?

settings.py seems like the perfect place to load that kind of data.

You can also simply use functools.cache to cache the function that returns the data indefinitely. Note that it will be cached per process, so if you are spinning up 4 workers (using gunicorn etc) you will cache 4 copies of the same data. If the data is too large consider using a separate service such as redis or memcached with Django's cache framework.

A module can still hold the data, even if it doesn't automatically load it when you import.  Modules are automatically cached so it's only initialized once.

You can use AppConfig to initialize the data : (See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/applications/)
class MyConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'my_app'

    def ready(self):
        self.my_data = ...  # Read data here

You can retrieve the data in the code of your views:
from django.apps import apps

def my_view(request, ...):
    my_var = apps.get_app_config('my_app').my_data

But in my opinion this is unnecessarily complex. You better do this in a module, as you yourself indicate:
# Note: the code below is not in a function or a class, but directly in the module!
# It will be executed only once when the server starts and the file is imported,
# `my_data` will continue to exist throughout server lifetime.

my_data = ... # Read data here.

def my_view(request, ...):
    my_var = my_data[...]  # You can use the data here 

And you can import the data in any other module, I don't see why it would lead to "unexpected side effects", as long as you make sure you don't introduce circular imports:
from my_module import my_data

def my_view(request, ...):
    my_var = my_data[...]  # You can use the data here 

This way, my_data will be initialized in a "predictable, deterministic fashion".
